# When did it become convention to not contest a rugby league scrum?

Tags: rugby-league

I'm aware that it is allowed to contest a scrum but it is rarely done, presumably because the ball can be fed directly to the Lock at back of the pack - has it always been like this or was there a watershed moment in the tactics or rules?

Comment: Allowing players who are not specifically trained for scrummage to do a scrum would be exceptionally dangerous. In rugby union, if a team is forced to play a player who is not a trained tight-five player in one of those position then the game goes to sissy-scrums because of how dangerous it is